# Does reading an XML file using Nokogiri require a root element?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am having problems reading an XML file when it doesn't contain a 'root'.

If I have a file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a>
<country>US</country>
</a>
<b>
<country>UK</country>
</b>
```

Nokogiri seems to only read the first element. If the XML file has a root element it seems to work fine.  I am using Nokogiri 1.5.6.

This works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<a>
<country>US</country>
</a>
<b>
<country>UK</country>
</b>
</root>
```

Comment: An XML file must have a single root element. A file with multiple "roots" isn't valid XML (to be precise: it is not well-formed.) you should not expect that an XML parser can handle that.

Comment: If you are creating this XML, you should fix it to be well-formed. If you are receiving badly-formed XML and need a parser to cope, that is a different matter. I couldn't find a Ruby forgiving parser on a brief look now, but there may well be one you could use, and someone here might be able to help you

Comment: I am using a public xml data file.  Thanks for looking for a parser, but I will probably modify the xml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a root element, it is not a complete XML document. You can either wrap the XML in a root element prior to parsing, or create a `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment` from it. i.e.

```
Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(str)
```

instead of:

```
Nokogiri::XML(str)
```

Ideally you fix whatever is creating the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Sitemaps do not have root elements. Sitemaps are XML documents and sitemap protocol defines it without a root element. http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html